# Getting Music NOT purchased from iTunes, from an old computer to new computer

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, music

I am trying to get my music NOT purchased from itunes into a new itunes/computer (the music I purchased from iTunes is on the new computer). i authorized it but keep getting an error message that says "authorization is needed to access "insert song name here".

i tried previously posted settings to get the autofill there to see if that works, and when i hit "apply" i get a message saying "The iPhone “Denise's iPhone” is synced with another iTunes library. Do you want to erase this iPhone and sync with this iTunes library? An iPhone can be synced with only one iTunes library at a time. Erasing and syncing replaces the contents of this iPhone with the contents of this iTunes library."

I do not want to "Erase and sync". In fact I want just the opposite. how can i get this music off an older phone/computer, onto an new computer (not just shared), then on to my new iphone?

Comment: Can't you copy the music files directly from computer 1 to computer 2 and import them into iTunes?

Comment: exactly wat patrix said...

Comment: I tried to buy one of those cords to connect the computers and that didn't work.  What is the easiest way to copy the files?  There are so many it would take forever to do it with a USB, but could go that route if that would work?  Sorry, I am pretty computer illiterate.

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two simple ways of achieving this:

1. Select the songs in iTunes and drag them to a folder in the Finder. Copy said folder to the other computer (via WiFi, external drive, Disk Target Mode, whatever). Drag files out of folder and drop on iTunes.
2. iTunes Match. For a cost of $25 per year, you can store all your music in iCloud. Whether you bought said music from iTunes, or ripped it from CD, or got it from anywhere. Then you can access it from all your devices - iPhones, iPads, Macs, iPod Touches, AppleTVs - anything that can see iCloud.

Comment: +1 on the iTunes Match. Have been using it for two years, and I love it. Having all my music on the go via iPad and iPhone is great. Plus I have it on my AppleTV, on my Macs...

Answer (score 1):

Get a high speed - solid state drive (that includes USB thumb sticks) or hard drive. And use this to transfer the files. iTunes should accept them fine if they have no DRM. iTunes have removed DRM from many songs recently (AFAIK).